# Testing Array.prototype.slice.call return value using jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am looking to test the return value from `Array.prototype.slice.call` and test it has actually been ran.

My function is as follows:

```
addEventToElements(className: string, eventType: string) {
        const queryResultNodeList = this.document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(className); // IE11 fix. IE11 does not support foreach on a NodeList
        const queryResultArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(queryResultNodeList);
        queryResultArray.forEach((element) => {
            if (eventType === 'mouse') {
                element.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => this.toggleMouseEvent(element));
                element.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => this.toggleMouseEvent(element));
            }
            if (eventType === 'click') {
                element.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    this.handleDropdownEvent(element)
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

In my jasmine test I am looking to test this line:

```
const queryResultArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(queryResultNodeList);
```

I am aware we shouldn't be testing core javascript functionality but I am looking to evaluate the return value and make sure this function is being called.

```
// Arrange
const el1 = document.createElement('div');
const el2 = document.createElement('div');
const queryResult = [el1,el2];
const arrayPrototypeSliceSpy = spyOn(Array.prototype, 'slice').and.returnValue(queryResult);


// Act
instance.addEventToElements('li[data-dropdown]');

// Assert
expect(arrayPrototypeSliceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This is my test above but it returns "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried creating your own function which just returns the result of Array.prototype.slice.call and then using that?

Comment: Why do you have to test implementation details? If somebody changes that line to `[...queryResultNodeList]` your test would fail but the *behaviour of the function* is going to remain. That latter thing is what you should be testing.

Comment: It seems that the test you need to write is that the correct event handler has been added to the correct items. Checking slice seems useless. Also, why aren't you just using NodeList.prototype.forEach()?

Comment: I'll bet you're getting the call stack error because spyOn is using Array.prototype.slice somewhere, but that's just speculation.

Comment: @CharlesBamford You might want to put that as an answer. (The solution is, as the OP already knows, not to test what functions are being called by replacing native js methods)

Answer (score 1):

You can't spy that method. Spy uses that [here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/main/src/core/Spy.js#L52). You know you shouldn't be trying to spy it, and you don't need to spy it, and trying to spy it creates a recursion, so you should probably stop.

As VLAZ said, you shouldn't test the implementation details of a function. All that is required is that given a set of inputs, the expected results happen.